# Show that $q\equiv_8 1$ when $q$ is an odd square number

Tags: ring-theory, congruences

**Problem:** *Given:* q is an odd squared number - *show that:* $q\equiv_8 1$

**My assumption:** $\forall q\in N:\exists a \in Z: a =1\pmod{2}$ and $a^2=q$.

Then I tried to show that it's only true satisfyingly if $\mathrm{gcd}(q,8)\mid 1 \leftrightarrow x\cdot q+y\cdot 8=1$.

But I don't know how to show that it is true for all numbers $q$.

All hints are welcome.

Comment: Can you rephrase as "Given (some condition), show that (some result)" please, as I can't work out which of your statements are conditions and which results. I could perhaps guess that your meaning is: "Given that q is an odd square number, show that $q\equiv 1 \pmod 8$" - would that be right?

Comment: yes that is right. i haved edited the question.

Comment: Does the notation $a\equiv_p b\iff a\equiv b\pmod p$ appear anywhere in scientific writing?

Comment: @user314 It certainly has been used on MSE before... off-hand, the only link I can find is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555895/what-are-some-examples-of-notation-that-really-improved-mathematics/556484#comment1189315_555939), but that doesn't establish that it is common/accepted.  I'm pretty sure I've seen Bill Dubuque use that notation in an answer or two, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any odd number is congruent to $1,3,5,7$ mod $8$. Each of these when squared gives remainder $1$ mod $8$.

Comment: how can I show that this is for all odd square numbers?

Comment: @SuperNova: any number mod 8 is 0,1,2,3..7. If remainder is 0,2,4,6 then number is even.

Comment: @Joffan: Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
1^2 = 1 &\equiv 1 \pmod 8\\
3^2=9 &\equiv 1 \pmod 8\\
5^2=25 &\equiv 1 \pmod 8\\
7^2=49 &\equiv 1 \pmod 8\\
(8q+k)^2 = 8q(8q+k) + 8qk +k^2 &\equiv k^2 \pmod 8\\
\end{align}$$